# How to fix form fields not appearing in html/django?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm very new to Django and was following a tutorial on creating a user registration page. However, when I run the server the form fields don't appear and only the Sign Up button is there.

I looked through many tutorials and tried to change the `UserForm` class thinking that that was the problem but I get the same issue.

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    class Meta:
           model = User
           fields = ["username", "email", "password"]
```

views.py

```
...
class UserFormView(View):
    form_class = UserForm
    template_name = 'static/register.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {"form":form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            #creates an object frm the form but doesnt save it into the database
            user = form.save(commit=False)

            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()

            #returns object if credenials are correct
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('main:homepage')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {"form":form})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

from django.conf.urls import url, include

app_name = "main"

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.homepage, name="homepage"),
    path("register/", views.UserFormView.as_view(), name='register'),
]
```

register.html

```
{% extends 'static/header.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <br>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button style="background-color:#F4EB16; color:blue" class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
    </form>

    If you already have an account <a href="/login" target="blank"><strong>login</strong></a> instead.

{% endblock %}
```

header.html

```
<html>
<head>
    {% load static %}
</head>
<body>
  <nav>
    <div style="background-color:green;">
      <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Title</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  {% block content %}
  {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

settings.py

```
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'main.apps.MainConfig',
]
...
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

I'm starting to think that the issue has something to do with one of the html codes, but it looks identical to the code in the tutorials.

Comment: mean submit or Sign Up button ? which one is there? any way dont use static as app name

Comment: I'm only using static to hold my html, css, and image files.

Comment: you need to use static folder to hold static file but not dynamic html files which contains interpolation like {{}}

Comment: I moved my html files into my main file but the form fields are still not showing when I run the server.

Comment: please place your dynamic html files inside app_name/templates/app_name/register.html then check. and  your code is fine i am getting corrects results. only you need to place html files in correct folders

Comment: right now I have my html files in app_name/main/register.html, I'm not too sure what you mean by /templates/

Comment: if your app is "main", then inside "main" there is a folder "templates". You should have all the templates for your app "main" in **/<your_project>/main/templates/main/register.html**